# Mediawiki raw output with newlines

Tags: newline, mediawiki, line-breaks

I can not understand why they would not want to support newlines in their raw ouput function. Does anyone know how to activate/hack it in MediaWiki?

Edit: I'm looking at the API right now, it is almost what I need, except it parse the wiki-text. So if anyone knows a way to disable this properly, that'd be sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ctype=text/css to the url.